# SFSE Users presenting at Dreamforce

Tags: discussion, dreamforce

Would love to know of any of you that are avid SFSE users that are presenting at Dreamforce.  Would make sure to catch some of those sessions.  Who on here is presenting?  and what are you presenting on?

Comment: I know LaceySnr and Metadaddy are presenting.

Answer (score 11):

These are the ones I quickly knew out of the top of my head, feel free to edit in the rest.

**Pat 'Metadaddy' Patterson & LaceySnr**

- Pushing the Boundaries: The Best of Salesforce StackExchange (Monday, November 18th: 5:30 PM - 6:00 PM
  Moscone Center West, Community Theater)

**Pat 'Metadaddy' Patterson & Chuck 'cmort' Mortimore**

- Single Sign-On and User Management for Portals and Communities (Monday, November 18th: 12:30 PM - 1:15 PM
  Moscone Center West, 2020)
- Single Sign-On and User Management with Salesforce Identity (Thursday, November 22nd: 12:15 PM - 1:00 PM
  Moscone Center West, 2011)

**Andrew Fawcett**, [summary and session links here](http://dreamforce.financialforce.com/sessions)

- Apex Enterprise Patterns: Building Strong Foundations (Tuesday, November 19th: 12:15 PM - 1:00 PM
  Moscone Center West, 2009 )
- Apex Code Analysis Using the Tooling API and Canvas (Tuesday, November 19th: 4:00 PM - 4:45 PM
  Moscone Center West, 2009)
- Building Help and Training to Make Every User an Expert (Monday, November 18th: 1:45 PM - 2:30 PM Moscone Center West, 2020)

**Stephen Willcock**

- Tests and Testability: Apex Structure and Strategy (Wednesday, November 20th: 9:00 AM - 9:45 AM
  Moscone Center West, 2024)

**Kevin P**

- NgForce: A JS Library For Quickly Building Salesforce Apps Using AngularJS (Monday, November 18th: 4:15 PM - 5:00 PM
  Moscone Center West, 2007)
- 2 more talks that elude me atm.

**Dan 'kibitzer' Appleman** , [his blog on his sessions](http://advancedapex.com/2013/10/22/dreamforce-2013-sessions/)

- High Reliability DML and Concurrency Design Patterns for Apex(Monday at 11:15am, Moscone West -2009)
- Community Success Zone Theater, Apex Design Patterns for Managed Packages (Monday at 1:30pm, Hilton San Francisco Union Square)
- Design Patterns for Asynchronous Apex (Tuesday at 5:15pm, Moscone West – 2024)

**Ralph Callaway / Calib Sidel**

- Force.com Advanced Developer Certification: Learn from the Experts (Tuesday at 10:30am, Moscone)

**Daniel Hoechst**

- Set Up Your Org Like a Pro (Tuesday, November 19th: 12:30 PM – 1:30 PM
  The Westin St. Francis San Francisco, Grand Ballroom)
- Answers Live 1 (Monday, November 18th: 12:30 PM – 1:30 PM
  The Westin St. Francis San Francisco, Grand Ballroom)

**Zach McElrath (zachelrath)**

- Build Killer Pages with Skuid (Wednesday, November 20th: 11:45 am - 12:15 pm Moscone Center West - Community Theater)
- Managing your Batch and Scheduled Apex processes with Relax (Thursday, November 21st: 11:30 AM - 12:00 PM Moscone Center West, Developer Theater)

**Benj Kamm (Benj)**

- [Health Leads: Building a Community](https://dreamevent.my.salesforce.com/apex/ActivityList#a093000000XfjtUAAR) (Wednesday, November 20th: 1130 am - 12:00 pm Hilton San Francisco Union Square, Foundation Theater)

Comment: sorry guys wont be attending dreamforce but will be looking for recordings of all the sessions .Excellent people with exceptional talent sharing knowledge !Exciting!!!